# Error Yard [Ruby]

Tags: ruby, gems

```
down vote
favorite
aleksiares@unit:~/wasteland/sokol_dev$ yard
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - .yardoc/processing (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/core_ext/file.rb:56:in `open!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/serializers/yardoc_serializer.rb:52:in `lock_for_writing' from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/registry_store.rb:197:in `lock_for_writing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/registry.rb:208:in `lock_for_writing'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb:251:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command.rb:13:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:71:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:53:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.9.5/bin/yard:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/yard:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/yard:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

При попытке самодокументировать код с помощью библиотеки Yard - вылезает следующая череда ошибок, не совсем понимаю, с чем это может быть связано.
Надеюсь, сможете что подсказать, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нет прав доступа к `~/wasteland/sokol_dev/.yardoc/processing`. Либо доступ уже кем-то занят, либо права выставлены неверно. Проверьте эти теории с помощью `ls` и `lsof`.

Comment: Странно, но этого файла там вообще нет

Comment: Точно нет? Или вы просто его **не видите**, потому что он скрыт (т. к. `.yardoc` начинается с точки)? Каким образом вы его искали?

Comment: Просмотрел содержимое каталога через консоль с помощью ls -a

Comment: Видимо, yard как раз и не смог его создать, получив ошибку о правах доступа. `touch` на место этого файла работает? Создаёт этот файл?

Comment: Да, файл был создан
При повторном вызове команды yard он удаляет этот файл

Comment: ...и после этого падает?

Comment: Да, та же ошибка, без каких-либо изменений

Comment: Значит, это что-то специфичное для вашей среды. Укажите ОС и (мало ли) файловую систему диска, на котором происходит дело. Если есть ещё что-то по вашему мнению релевантное -- тоже добавьте. У меня проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: ОС - ubuntu 14.04, файловая система-  ext4, ruby ставил через rvm, версия - 2.2.0, есть теперь подозрения, что проблемы версии могут быть, ибо ещё косяк с тем, что он не хочет обновлять её до более новой - 2.3, например.

Comment: В смысле, "не хочет"?

Comment: Выдаёт серию ошибок
There was an error(23).
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

Downloading https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 failed.
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.

Comment: Это подозрительно. Указывает на проблемы с сетью или что-то другое из этой оперы. Попробуйте обновить RVM и/или запретить бинарные сборки (ставить из исходников, у RVM есть какой-то флаг для этого).

Comment: Похимичив решёл ту проблему, но появилась новая, теперь при обработке выдаёт большое количество предупреждений и ошибку
"Cannot resolve link to Rails.root from text"